# Densities of subsets related to the exponential function

Tags: number-theory, density-function

Let $A$ be the set of natural numbers $n$ such that $[e^n]$ is even and $B$ the set of $n$ such that $[e^n]$ is odd, where $[-]$ denotes the floor function and $e^{x}$ the exponential function.

> Question: What are the densities of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: An other way to formulate the problem: $[e^n] \text{ is even } \Leftrightarrow \exists k : \log(2k) \leq n < \log(2k+1)$.